# i need to output "no mode" if more than one number is repeated the same amount of times

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

i cant figure out how to print "no mode" if there is more than one number that is repeated the same amount of times for ex. 5 5 6 6 7 6 9; since 5 and 6 are both repeated twice i want to print out "no mode" here is the algorithm im using to find the mode:

```
int mostfound = *pScores;
int most_found_count = 0;
int currentnum = *pScores;
int current_num_count = 0;
bool noMode = true;


//finding the mode
for (int i =  0; i < numScores; i++)
{
  if (*(pScores + i) == currentnum) 
  {
     current_num_count++;
  }
  else {
      if (current_num_count > most_found_count) 
        {
              mostfound = currentnum; 
              most_found_count = current_num_count;
              noMode = false;

        }
  else if (current_num_count == most_found_count)
        {
            noMode = true;

        }

       currentnum = *(pScores + i); 
       current_num_count = 1;
  }
}

cout << mostfound << endl;
        cout << currentnum << endl;
        cout << most_found_count << endl;

cout << "Mode: " << mostfound << endl;
```

}

Comment: Although the frequency of occurrence can be easily calculated through maps, for this particular code, it will help if you explain your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

std::multiset could help you out

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;
....
multiset<int> setScores;
for (int i =  0; i < numScores; i++)
{
    setScores.insert(pScores[i]);
}
// setScores here got items = (a number being repeated)
// and count = (how many times number repeated)
multiset<int> setRepeats;
for (multiset<int>::iterator it = setScores.begin(); it!=setScores.end(); it++)
{
    setRepeats.insert(setScores.count(*it));
}
// setRepeats here got items = (how many times a number repeated) 
// and count = (how many different numbers repeated this amount of times)
// Now search for count that > 1
noMode = false;
for (multiset<int>::iterator it1 = setRepeats.begin(); it1!=setRepeats.end(); it1++)
{
    if(setRepeats.count(*it1)>1)
    {
        noMode = true;
        break;
    }
}
// Now use noMode as you wish
```

PS Note the number 6 in your sample array is repeated 3 times, but number 5 repeated only twice, so noMode will be false

Comment: Perhaps he means consecutively?

Comment: Maybe, "consecutively" could fit the task into his result. If so, my code is a junk then, the algorithm must be rewritten totally